# Error upon integrating JNDI with Spring

Tags: oracle, spring, datasource, tomcat6, jndi

This was my first attempt at Spring with JNDI but getting the below mentioned exception when trying to create the ApplicationContext like:

```java
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("master-job.xml");
```

The Spring configuration file is as follows:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="/jdbc/Eqpstatus"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="masterDao" class="com.dao.MasterDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

On Server i have the required resource entry for the JNDI name.

```xml
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        maxActive="10" maxIdle="2" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/Eqpstatus"
        password="xxxx" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx) (PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx) (PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xyz)))"
        username="xxx"/>
```

The error i see is:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
```

Would highly appreciate any inputs on this as am new to Spring-JNDI integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Tomcat and everything is fine with your Tomcat configuration; this should be enough:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource" />
```

Where `jdbc/dataSource` is the name defined in your Tomcat config.

**EDIT:**

My bad, forgot about the jndi.properties; there are two possibilities:

- either provide a jndi.properties on your classpath or
- set the values in a in the `<jee:jndi-environment/>` element of  `<jee:jndi-lookup />` (see [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee))

The `java.naming.factory.initial` property needs to be set for sure, to something like `org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory`, possibly some other values as well, like:

```
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming  
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs.prefixes=org.apache.naming  
java.naming.provider.url=org.apache.naming
```

Also see [reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).

Comment: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: After changing the jndiName property to "/jdbc/Eqpstatus" and adding resourceRef property to true, the error i see now is - javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context

Comment: the jndiName property in which config file? can you edit your question with your current config files? Spring and Tomcat as well

Comment: jndiName in the Spring configuration file. Have edited my question.

Comment: if you are using Tomcat you need to use java:comp/env/jdbc/Eqpstatus. Do you have jndi.properties? Have you also tried the dedicated jee schema?

Comment: I do not use jndi.properties. Tried dedicated jee schema with above properties and saw the error
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you should use the dedicated tag instead of declaring a "JndiObjectFactoryBean" bean :

```xml
<!-- JNDI DataSource for J2EE environments -->         
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jdbc/rppsDS-PUB-PROTO" default-ref="localDataSource" />

<!-- local dataSource for JUnit integration tests -->
<bean id="localDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Then, you need a jndi.properties file (which could be directly in application server dir such as JBoss) with a content similar to :

```java
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099
```

Comment: Am using Tomcat 6 as web server and i have added the entry on server.xml above which includes all these configuration that you have in localDataSource bean.

Comment: Well, if you use Tomcat, you don't need these jnp parameters, you just need to define a "Resource" in "GlobalNamingResources". Maybe you're trying to run a JUnit test (which can not use jndi datasource). By the way, Are you sure this datasource is a valid jdbc datasource ? Don't u have errors when u start Tomcat ?

Comment: I am not trying to run the application and not Junit tests. The datasource is valid and there are no errors upon starting Tomcat.

Comment: You are not trying to run the application, and you are not running JUnit tests, so can you explain what you are trying which gives you errors ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant i am trying to run the application and not Junit tests.

Comment: @John C: can you check my answer? that solution also gives you an error? If so, can you post it?